# Error with rails_admin authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a User model which has a boolean attribute called 'admin'.

I want to avoid users accessing `/admin (rails_admin)`, so I added this in my `/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
config.authorize_with do
  redirect_to main_app.root_path unless warden.user.admin?
end
```

And when trying to access /admin, I get:

```
undefined method `root_path' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x96d2ec4>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show your routes file?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a root route for your app.

For example, add in your config/routes.rb (Rails 4)

```
root 'home#index'
```

This will point to the action index in HomeController.

For Rails 3 you should use:

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

Hope it helps.